# Snowflake sql how to open an array

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake Database, I've got a table where I got an array column.
most pf the times there is only 1 value in the array, but can be up to 100.
I'm trying to open the array that will give each cell a different raw.

Here is an example of a single row in the table:

```
"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]
```

Tried using "flatten" function, but each time I get an error:

> Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

For example:

```
select * 
from  FISH_OF_FORTUNE_DEV.DWH.FACT_DAILY_REVENUE, 
 table(flatten ( 
     select currencies_added 
     from FISH_OF_FORTUNE_DEV.DWH.FACT_DAILY_REVENUE
  ) )f ;
```

see image:
[Rows in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xpXF.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all information directly to your question, preferably as editable text. Also please update your question with the result you want to achieve, based on your sample data

Comment: You still haven't updated your question with the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these arrays are stored in a variant columns or arrays and have been parsed as JSON, you'd want to use a lateral flatten.  This code uses a CTE to use your same provided, rather than a table:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT parse_json('[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]') as var)
SELECT x.var, y.value, y.value:Gems::number
FROM x,
lateral flatten(input=>var) y;
```

Output in my query:

1. original value
2. value after flatten
3. value after flatten for Gems cast to a number

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mike, few more examples of using `FLATTEN`.

Using below data-set in original form (no flatten) -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('{"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]}')
)
select parse_json(colname) from cte;

| PARSE_JSON(colname)     |
|-------------------------|
| {                       |
|   "currencies_added": [ |
|     {                   |
|       "Gems": 24000     |
|     },                  |
|     {                   |
|       "Gems": 1250      |
|     }                   |
|   ]                     |
| }                       |
```

Flatten only the column -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('{"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]}')
)
select value from cte, 
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(colname));

+-------------------+
| VALUE             |
|-------------------|
| [                 |
|   {               |
|     "Gems": 24000 |
|   },              |
|   {               |
|     "Gems": 1250  |
|   }               |
| ]                 |
+-------------------+
1 Row(s) produced.
```

Flatten to get the array (will produce two rows, corresponding to two array elements) -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('{"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]}')
)
select value from cte, 
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(colname):"currencies_added");

| VALUE           |
|-----------------|
| {               |
|   "Gems": 24000 |
| }               |
| {               |
|   "Gems": 1250  |
| }               |
```

Flatten array elements  -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('{"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]}')
)
select lf2.key, lf2.value from cte, 
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(colname):"currencies_added") lf1, 
lateral flatten(input=>lf1.value) lf2;
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Gems | 24000 |
| Gems | 1250 |

OR, you can use `recursive` clause -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('{"currencies_added":[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]}')
)
select lf1.key, lf1.value from cte,
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(colname):"currencies_added", recursive=>TRUE) lf1 
where key is NOT NULL;
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Gems | 24000 |
| Gems | 1250 |

Using as array only -

```
with cte(colname) as (
select * from values
('[{"Gems": 24000},{"Gems": 1250}]')
)
select lf1.key, lf1.value from cte,
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(colname), recursive=>TRUE) lf1
where key is NOT NULL;
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Gems | 24000 |
| Gems | 1250 |